# Google streetview is dark (even on official service url)

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

Can't understand why today in all my browsers (and several machines) i see dark screen on my google streetview (in my project) and in official websites
https://www.google.com/maps/@53.8746594,27.5661324,3a,75y,304.5h,93t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMOtE1LgNjBFLwTq3K02g8aKS8xEUhY6E5c_wcf%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-2.9999962-ya4.500001-ro-0-fo100!7i6144!8i3072

https://www.google.com/streetview/

Some people said there were problems if hardware acceleration turned on, but it doesn't work if i turn it off

Previously it worked well, started since June 1st.

Comment: Both the links in your question work for me in Chrome.

Comment: @geocodezip most likely you opened the pages when service was up again or you are from country where it worked without a problems.

Answer (score 0):

Google streetview service was down for most part of Europe from June 1, 2018 up to June 4, 2018 (~16:00 GMT+3, don't know whether it didn't work for the whole timeframe)

If you see black googel streetview on your page, try to open original services links and see if this works:
https://www.google.com/streetview/
https://www.instantstreetview.com/@46.948517,7.455004,-112.17h,5p,1z

Info about google downtime can be found here: 
http://downdetector.com/status/google
http://downdetector.com/status/google/map/

If you see black google streetview screen on your web page try to trigger window.resize event or just resize your window, of course it's not this case when google streetview service down itself.

I saw the information that it didn't work because of turned on hardware acceleration.